# How to style text node with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<div id='app'>{{ userContent }}</div>
```

In `userContent`, if a line starts with `-` I want to style only that line red. I can modify `userContent` data in js with the class for those lines and use `v-html` but then I lose XSS protection. Is there any way to have XSS protection with Vue.js but also be able to style the `userContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is possible without creating new elements from the user provided string.

You could parse the string yourself using a regular expression to match the lines starting with a hyphen, something like `(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\n)` or `\-(.*?)\n`, wrap that content in a new element with a class, and then style it, but you would then need to inject that back into the html, which I believe would then open you up to XSS, same as with v-html.

To my knowledge and after a quick search there doesnt seem to be any way to do this purely with CSS.